# Removing a select value from a list javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a dorp down list being populated from a Json array, which is fine, but when i am editing my selections, i need to remove the option that is already selected so it doesn't appear twice

```
for (i = 0; i < datain.length; i++) {
    if (datain[i].Name == course) {
        selectedCourseId = datain[i].Id;
        selectedCourseName = datain[i].Name;
    }
    $('#EditCourseSelect').append($('<option></option>').attr("value", datain[i].Id).text(datain[i].Name));

}
$('#EditCourseSelect').prepend("<option value=" + selectedCourseId + " selected='selected'>" + selectedCourseName + "</option>");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to avoid creating it in the for loop, so that you don't have to delete it

```
for (i = 0; i < datain.length; i++) {
    if (datain[i].Name == course) {
        selectedCourseId = datain[i].Id;
        selectedCourseName = datain[i].Name;
    } else {
        $('#EditCourseSelect').append($('<option></option>').attr("value", datain[i].Id).text(datain[i].Name));
    }
}

$('#EditCourseSelect').prepend("<option value=" + selectedCourseId + " selected='selected'>" + selectedCourseName + "</option>");
```

Comment: Here you are adding selected item as a first option always. If you need to show the dropdown options as per the order in the JSON array, then it will be not handle this way. And as you are looping through each item so handle it inside the loop is more appropriate instead of adding this outside the loop. Anyways OP accepted the answer! I just want to mentioned regarding the order.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal though your comment is relevant, it is not really inside the scope of the question imho

Answer (score 1):

Just use `CSS selector`

```
$('#EditCourseSelect option:selected').remove()
```

or with `jQuery` [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('#EditCourseSelect').find("option:selected").remove()
```

while [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Test it in the [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQYxXe) that i made for you

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid adding duplicate record while you are creating option for your dropdown. It's better to not add twice instead of adding twice and remove one. Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/L8g547kf/1/).

```
var datain = [{'Id': 1, 'Name': 'jQuery'}, {'Id': 2, 'Name': 'PHP'}, {'Id': 3, 'Name': 'JavaScript'}, {'Id': 4, 'Name': 'HTML5'}, {'Id': 5, 'Name': 'CSS3'}];
var course = 'CSS3';
for (i = 0; i < datain.length; i++) {
    if (datain[i].Name == course) {
        $('#EditCourseSelect').append($('<option></option>').attr("value", datain[i].Id).prop('selected', true).text(datain[i].Name));
    } else {
        $('#EditCourseSelect').append($('<option></option>').attr("value", datain[i].Id).text(datain[i].Name));
    }
}
```

If the `course` you pass matched the `Name` in the loop then just add `prop('selected', true)` as extra option else not.